# Poor performance when downscaling surfaces

Tags: cairo

I am using PyCairo to write a chess game, each piece is a 512x512 `ImageSurface`. The pieces need to scale up and down. When the scale (x or y) is less than 1.0, the app is painfully slow, with only 32 pieces. When scale is equal to or greater than 1.0, it is blisteringly fast.

I have tried `canvas.set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_NONE)`, with no good results. I have tried both `cr.set_scale()` and `surface.set_device_scale()` with the same poor performance. Is there any way to scale down faster, with possibly lower quality, which is acceptable?

I thought of recreating surfaces every time the chess board is resized, and use a scale of 1.0 in that case. However it will choke as the user resizes the window.

Comment: To what kind of surface are you drawing the image surfaces? Is it to something provided by GTK? If so, you could try using `cairo_surface_create_similar()` once to create a 512x512 surface (for each chess piece) and copy the images to that. Afterwards, drawing from this similar surface to the target surface should be faster. (E.g. in X11: Cairo no longer has to upload image data, but can tell the X11 server to do the whole operation server-side.)

Answer (score 0):

After you set the surface pattern as a source in a cairo context, do `cairo_pattern_set_filter(cairo_get_source(cr), CAIRO_FILTER_FAST);`. I think this means that 'nearest' is used as the scaling algorithm.

Comment: You're right, changing the filter made it 60 FPS. There is of course less quality. I think I will use the fast filter while the window is resized, and redraw with quality once the resize stops.